# Borland Database engine on Windows 10 (1703)

Tags: database, delphi, windows-10, bde

Since Win10pro (1606) Borland Database Engine worked fine. I installed Win10pro build 1703 and when i run Database Desktop, it open saying that private and working dirs are invalid or undefined (administrator mode) and then, clicking OK, just closes.
In my Delphi10 BDE is installed and runs ok. But my problem is that i can't open my paradox tables outside of my applications.
Any help, please ?

Comment: I installed BDE with this zipped file 30359_bde_installer_for_rad_studio_delphi_c_builder_10_seattle which i downloaded from embarcadero's site.
After installation i add the BDE package from inside the IDE where it runs ok.
My apps also run ok. In the registry there isn't Borland/databaseEngine key (as existed in the past).
I put UAC in lowest level but still not BDE running after the first two messages for the initial dirs.

Comment: BDE is not compatible with Vista UAC (its filesystem virtualization part, in particular). You MAY try running BDE Administrator  elevated ("as admin") and set there private/working dirs. the same as are set in non-elevated BDE Administrator. But there is no warranties. You may also look into UAC Virtual Store and try to find there BDE/IDAPI files redirected, like the paradox lock files typically placed in C:\ root. And then you may try to move them out of VS into their before-Vista locations. But no warrantied. BDE is long non-maintained and UAC drives it crazy.

Comment: The problem is with DataBase desktop. I run it elevated but shows me the errors i mentioned and then closes. Even setting UAC to lowest level.
The problem comes up after Win10 pro (1703) installation. With Win10pro (1607) there wasn't any problem.

Comment: BDE is a library, not a separate process server. So if you run DBD elevated, then DBD loads BDE elevated. And elevated BDE might have different settings (idapi.cfg or something) than non-elevated BDE. Same holds for BDE Admin, another application that loads and uses BDE library. You may install and run Microsoft Process Monitor and compare registry and file I/O traces of an elevated and non-elevated programs using BDE library inside them

Comment: May be you can use my "replacement" **PdxEditor** (for Paradox & dBase files) available as freeware from my website [www.nknabe.dk/database](http://www.nknabe.dk/database).
Though not a full replacement for the Borland Database Desktop, it has some new features, manages most tasks, and runs without any problems on 32- og 64-bit Windows, even with Windows 10 in it's recent release 1709 (2018). Please have a look at the comparative feature matrix.
Best Regards